# Nativescript android:exported android-12 compatibility error even after adding android:exported in all activity, service and receiver tags

Tags: android, nativescript, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, android-12

```js
{
    "version": "2.10.1",
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "code-clean": "prettier --write \"src\"",
        "ngcc": "ngcc",
        "postinstall": "patch-package"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.5",
        "@angular/router": "~12.2.5",
        "@mapo80/nativescript-ngx-shadow": "file:packages/mapo80-nativescript-ngx-shadow-7.0.1.tgz",
        "@nativescript-community/ui-image": "4.0.20",
        "@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottom-navigation": "^7.0.25",
        "@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottomsheet": "^7.0.28",
        "@nativescript-community/ui-pager": "13.0.31",
        "@nativescript/angular": "^12.2.0",
        "@nativescript/appversion": "~2.0.0",
        "@nativescript/camera": "^5.0.13",
        "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.1",
        "@nativescript/fingerprint-auth": "^8.1.0",
        "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
        "@nativescript/geolocation": "8.0.2",
        "@nativescript/imagepicker": "~1.0.0",
        "@nativescript/iqkeyboardmanager": "~2.0.0",
        "@nativescript/social-share": "^2.0.4",
        "@nativescript/theme": "^3.0.2",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^9.2.0",
        "@ngrx/entity": "^12.2.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0",
        "@nstudio/nativescript-exoplayer": "~5.0.0",
        "@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^3.0.2",
        "@sergeymell/nativescript-svg": "^1.1.2",
        "@sonnytrujillojr/tokenizerjs": "^1.0.1",
        "ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum": "file:packages/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum",
        "deep-diff": "^1.0.2",
        "immer": "^7.0.9",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
        "nativescript-drop-down": "^6.0.2",
        "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^3.0.2",
        "nativescript-gradient": "^2.0.1",
        "nativescript-image-swipe": "^5.0.1",
        "nativescript-masked-text-field": "file:packages/nativescript-masked-text-field-4.0.3.tgz",
        "nativescript-mediafilepicker": "4.0.2",
        "nativescript-push-notifications": "^1.1.6",
        "nativescript-status-bar": "file:nativescript-status-bar",
        "nativescript-ui-listview": "^9.1.0",
        "ngrx-store-logger": "^0.2.4",
        "normalizr": "^3.6.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.18",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.5",
        "@nativescript/android": "8.1.1",
        "@nativescript/ios": "8.1.0",
        "@nativescript/types": "~8.1.0",
        "@nativescript/webpack": "^5.0.8",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "^12.2.5",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
        "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
        "babel-types": "6.26.0",
        "babylon": "6.18.0",
        "codelyzer": "~4.0.2",
        "commitizen": "^4.2.3",
        "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
        "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
        "prettier": "2.0.5",
        "prettier-tslint": "^0.4.2",
        "tslint": "~5.8.0",
        "typescript": "~4.3.5"
    },
    "readme": "NativeScript Application",
    "config": {
        "commitizen": {
            "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
        }
    },
    "main": "./src/main.ts"
}
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="__PACKAGE__" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0">

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />

    <application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:exported="true">

        <activity android:name="net.demo.Activity" android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode" android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden | adjustPan" android:exported="true">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="link.demo.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="link.demo.com" />
                <data android:scheme="net.demo" android:host="demo.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity" android:exported="true"/>

        <service android:name="org.nativescript.plugins.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="org.nativescript.plugins.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/nativescript_google_maps_api_key"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am working on a nativescript project. The app is working perfectly fine in development mode but as soon as I am creating a .aab file and trying to upload the bundle to the play store I am getting the following error regarding android 12 compatibility

Error - You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

I tried following the doc link specified in the error message and also tried solutions that stated things like adding android:exported in all activity, service and receiver tags in which intent-filter is there. I tried these solutions but nothing worked. Can someone help me or guide me with tackling this issue?

Comment: Please share your manifest and package.json so we can look at what plugins you're using as well as full config.

Comment: I've posted both the manifest and package.json file

Comment: Any updates/solution ?